# render data from firebase with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how do I render data from firebase in react ? I tried this code but nothing is showing up !
isn't users an array ?
because when I put something like this `users = [1, 2, 3]` it works.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from './axios-users';

class App extends Component {

render() {
let users = [];
axios.get('/users.json')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        users = response.data;
} );
const listItems = users.map((users) =>
  <li>{users}</li>
);
return (
  <div className="App">
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  </div>
);
}
}
export default App;
```

console.log(response.data)

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is anything related to firebase in the code you have shared.

Comment: the data is coming from firebase using `axios.get('/users.json')`

Comment: You're doing an axios call in your RENDER. That's just a big no no, do it in `componentDidMount`. Also, axios calls are asynchronous, so it's not going to wait for the axios call to finish. So `users` is going to still be an empty array when you return. Store users in state in axios callback and then render the state

Answer (score 0):

You can use state for this work because you are doing async work with axios that is why users will assign after when view render.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "./axios-users";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
super();
    this.state = {
      users: []
    };
    this.handleAxiosAction();
  }

  handleAxiosAction = () => {
    axios.get("/users.json").then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({ users: response.data });
    });
  };



      render() {
    const listItems = this.state.users.map(user => <li key={user.id}>{user}</li>);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>{listItems}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
export default App;
```

Comment: Making an AJAX call in the `constructor` is considered to be a bad practice. See this: https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-component-life-cycle-823a640b3e8d

Comment: should I add `super()` before `this.state` ?

Comment: `this.state.users.map is not a function` :(

Comment: What you are getting in ` response.data` ? It should be a Array otherwise I will throw error.

Comment: array of arrays

Comment: @NishantDixit I added the console result in the question

Comment: @AbdelhakAj It is not coming a Array It is a object which has a key -LEO.... and value of key(-LEO....) is coming array, You are using {user.id} in your code where It is in whole response? there is no key which have name "id"

Comment: What actually you want to achieve with current response?

Comment: i just want to render those users to the screen